# Java 2 Dimensional Array Constructor

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array, constructor

I need to make a constructor for a 2 dimensional array.

It should look like this:

```
public ClassName(double[][] input)
```

When I want to use this later on, I would type in ClassName num1=new ClassName(????). I have been stuck on this for hours with no idea what I am supposed to put inside the parentheses to set the size of the array. I have tried everything in my limited beginner knowledge from trying [5][5] to 5,5 to 5 to double[5][5] to double[5][5] input, and so on and so forth.

Please help....

Thank you.

Comment: add the code you already have

Comment: public class Terrain {
 private double rowCol;
 private double[][] map;
 public Terrain(int square){
  double[][]heights=new double[square][square];
  for(int i=0;i<heights.length;i++)
  {
   for(int j=0;j<heights[0].length;j++)
   {
    heights[i][j]=Math.random()*100;
    //System.out.printf("%.1f",heights[i][j]);
    //System.out.print(" ");
   }
   //System.out.println();
  }
  rowCol=square;
  map=heights;
 }
I used (int square) to try and get around using (double[][] heights) and it was working okay until I was not able to access the array for another part. So I guess i need to use it...

Comment: is there a better way to post the code, the formatting is very bad

Comment: @javanoob yes edit your original post and put it in there. Make sure to use formatting for code (4 spaces before each line)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This example is more clear create your own class.

```
 public class ClassName { /* Attributes */ 
    private double[][] array;

    /* Constructor */
    public ClassName (double[][] array) {
    this.array = array;
   }
}
```

In other class when you invock your class to do this

```
public class Test {

public static void main(String[] args) {
 double[][] arr = new double[5][5];

 ClassName num1 = new ClassName(arr);
  num1.myMethod();//do something
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to instantiate the array when it is being passed in as an anonymous array (meaning you don't already have a variable with the array in it). You haven't given the code you have tried but my assumption would be that you are leaving out the `new` keyword.

```
ClassName num1 = new ClassName(new double[x][y]);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can declare array first and then allot memory for it using new operator.

```
double input[][];
input = new double[size][size];

//simply use 
double input[][] = new double[size][size];

//for class use
YourClass instance = new YourCLass(input);
```

Answer (score 0):

You might need something like:

```
double[][] input = new double[5][5];

// initialize arr here

ClassName num1 = new ClassName(input);
```

Comment: but I am required to use it as public ClassName(double[][] input). would i be able to incorporate your suggestion?

Comment: @javanoob Yes I think so, you can keep your constructor definition as `public ClassName(double[][] input)`.